# Moving and deleting rows between MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following query to move rows from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` VALUES (SELECT * FROM `old_table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5)
```

However, I need to delete the rows from the `old_table` once I move them. Is that possible using a similar query to the one above?

Thanks,

joel

Comment: Is there a problem in using two consecutive queries? First copy and then delete.

Comment: Edited the question with order by rand() and LIMIT... I would be happy if you can help me with the necessary DELETE query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no choice

```
alter table old_table add column selected int(1) not null default 0;
update old_table set selected=1 order by rand() limit 5;
insert into new_table select * from old_table where selected=1;
delete from old_table where selected=1;
```

or you wrap it as stored procedure, function

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try to run the following query: "INSERT INTO table_new (Name) VALUES (SELECT Name FROM table_old)", I get SQL error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Name FROM table_old)' at line 1"

Comment: trim to this ? `INSERT INTO table_new (Name) SELECT Name FROM table_old;`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

When inserting a subset of the data, you will need to follow the `INSERT` with a `DELETE`, if you are using InnoDB, wrap it in a transaction so that the action is atomic.

With `ORDER BY RAND()` you would have a major issue, as you would not know what rows had been deleted.  A temporary table to store the target rows would probably be needed.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `target_keys`
    SELECT `id` FROM `old_table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5;

INSERT INTO `new_table` VALUES
    (SELECT * FROM `old_table` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `target_keys`));

DELETE FROM `old_table` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `target_keys`);

DROP TABLE `target_keys`;

COMMIT;
```

---

**Pre-Edit Answer**

If you are moving all of the rows as in your example, why not just [rename the table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)?

```
RENAME TABLE old_name TO new_name
```

If it is a subset of the data, then you will need to follow the `INSERT` with a `DELETE`, if you are using InnoDB, wrap it in a transaction so that the action is atomic.

Comment: Sorry, I am using a subset of data. I edited the example with ORDER BY RAND() and the LIMIT clause. How can i use the DELETE in that case?